# ExtJS 4 rowexpander with grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can I solve Grid Row Expander with child grid? Getting value as a plain text works fine.

Is there any way we can create a Grid inside a Grid to get value from JSON data?

I want to create this structure using MVC architecture.

```
Ext.define('CSApp.view.ContentGrid',
{
 extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
 store: 'Details',
 width: 840,
 height:45,
 initComponent: function()
 {
 this.columns = [
 {header: 'TASK ID', dataIndex: 'taskID', flex:1},
 {header: 'ITEM', dataIndex: 'name', flex:1},
 {header: 'EXISTING VALUE', dataIndex: 'value', flex:1},
 {header: 'NEW VALUE', dataIndex: 'newValue', flex:1}];
 this.callParent(arguments);
 }
});
```

Comment: Code showing what you have tried and a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: don't forget to mark accepted answers please.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar scenario: a list of customers with their own record data (address, phone, account balance, etc...) each customer also had an account with a set of "paid for" items. In other words I needed a grid of customers that could be rowexpanded to open their own "Account Grid" showing a grid of items with related data about the items, how much they paid, etc.

I slimmed out a bunch of disrelated configs and other code but here's an example of the view I used for the "outer" grid:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.CustomerGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.customergrid',
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.RowExpander'
    ],
    title: 'Customer Grid',
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        pluginId: 'rowexpander',
        selectRowOnExpand: true,

        // this gives each row a unique identifier based on record's "acct_no"
        rowBodyTpl: [
            '<div id="AccountGridRow-{acct_no}" ></div>'
        ],

        // stick a grid into the rowexpander div whenever it is toggled open
        toggleRow: function(rowIdx) {
            var rowNode = this.view.getNode(rowIdx),
                row = Ext.get(rowNode),
                nextBd = Ext.get(row).down(this.rowBodyTrSelector),
                hiddenCls = this.rowBodyHiddenCls,
                record = this.view.getRecord(rowNode),
                grid = this.getCmp(),
                acctNo = record.get('acct_no'),
                targetId = 'AccountGridRow-' + acctNo;

            if (row.hasCls(this.rowCollapsedCls)) {
                row.removeCls(this.rowCollapsedCls);
                this.recordsExpanded[record.internalId] = true;
                this.view.fireEvent('expandbody', rowNode, record, nextBd.dom);

                if (rowNode.grid) {
                    nextBd.removeCls(hiddenCls);
                    rowNode.grid.doComponentLayout();
                    rowNode.grid.view.refresh();
                } else {

                    // this is the store for the inner grid
                    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        model: 'MyApp.model.Account',
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax', 
                            url: 'customers',
                            reader: 'json'
                            extraParams: {
                                account: acctNo
                            }
                        },
                        autoLoad: {
                            callback: function() {

                                // create the inner grid and render it to the row
                                nextBd.removeCls(hiddenCls);
                                var grid = Ext.create('MyApp.view.AccountGrid', { // <-- this is my "inner" grid view
                                        renderTo: targetId,
                                        store: this,
                                        row: row
                                    });

                                rowNode.grid = grid;

                                // I didn't want to listen to events from the inner grid
                                grid.suspendEvents(); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                row.addCls(this.rowCollapsedCls);
                nextBd.addCls(this.rowBodyHiddenCls);
                this.recordsExpanded[record.internalId] = false;
                this.view.fireEvent('collapsebody', rowNode, record, nextBd.dom);
            }
        }
    }],
    columns: [/* a bunch of column configs for the outer grid... */],
    store: Ext.getStore('StudentList') // <-- the outer grid store

});
```

Basically I just overrode the `toggleRow` function to stick another grid (`MyApp.view.AccountGrid`) into the rowexpander div.

This worked out very well and the app is completed now.

I have the data for the inner "account" grid in a cached object so that the ajax returns within 50 - 100 ms. If you had some kind of long query to get the inner grid data I could see this being unworkable.

Comment: HI Geronimo, Thanks for your code. I tried your code and modified field names. But i m getting 
"TypeError: component is undefined
var type = component.xtype || defaultType," Error...

Comment: What are you using for your "inner" grid view (the one inside the row)? In my code I am creating a `MyApp.view.AccountGrid` but I didn't include the code for that view in the snippet above.

Comment: Hi Geronimo,Sorry for late reply. code above i added for inner grid. I modified my question. please check. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 2):

RowExpander does not allow for a nested grid structure. All it allows is to insert any HTML in the row body. Which means that you can create an HTML table inside the expanded row, but it is not another Ext Grid.